# lock some version so that it is not updated again

Tags: firefox, update-manager

I have to install Adobe Flash Player, each time Firefox is updated. I am tired of this .... hectic work. Please tell me how to prevent Firefox from being updated by Update-Manager.

Comment: Try using Synaptic Package Manager to lock a package's version. Follow [this guide](http://www.ubuntugeek.com/how-to-lock-package-versions-from-synaptic-package-manager.html)

Comment: Won't that only prevent updating via Synaptic? OP wants to stop updating even by Update Manager.

Comment: possible dup: http://askubuntu.com/questions/18654/how-to-prevent-updating-of-a-specific-package

Comment: BTW, why do you have to install "Adobe Flash Player" each time Firefox updates? I get the feeling there are more updates to AFP than to Firefox in a given period. And how is it hectic work? Tell us more about your system.

Comment: Actually ... when I run update-manager, firefox get updated if there is any update for it. Then I start my firefox and find "you need to install Adobe Flash Player".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Open a terminal (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd>) and enter this command:

`echo "firefox hold" | sudo dpkg --set-selections`

This command locks your package and prevents it to be updated.

**Undo**

If for any reason you change your mind and want to update it, simply replace *hold* with *install*:

`echo "firefox install" | sudo dpkg --set-selections`

**Check status**

To check the status of a package if it will be updated, enter:

`dpkg --get-selections | grep firefox`

**Note** it’s better to lock other packages related to *firefox* as well, such as *firefox-globalmenu*, *firefox-gnome-support*. You can see all of them by checking the status, then enter the lock command for each separately:

`echo "firefox-globalmenu hold" | sudo dpkg --set-selections`

`echo "firefox-gnome-support hold" | sudo dpkg --set-selections`

`echo "firefox-locale-en hold" | sudo dpkg --set-selections`

– these are just examples, on your computer you may have different locale packages.